# Listen to changes in a value inside an object in React context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Given the following React Context Provider. A simple `Counter` class with 2 methods, stored in the React context.

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

class Counter {
  public count: number = 0;

  getCount = () => {
    return this.count;
  };

  incrementCount = () => {
    this.count = this.count + 1;
  };
}

type CounterContextType = {
  counter: Counter;
};

const defaults: CounterContextType = {
  counter: new Counter()
};

const CounterContext = createContext<CounterContextType>(defaults);

export const CounterProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const counter = new Counter();

  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider
      value={{
        counter
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useCounter = () => {
  return useContext(CounterContext);
};
```

I want to listen to changes in the `count` property of the `Counter` instance.

Here is what I have tried:

```
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { CounterProvider, useCounter } from "./CounterProvider";

const DisplayWithMethod = () => {
  const { counter } = useCounter();

  return <div>Method: {counter.getCount()}</div>;
};

const DisplayWithProperty = () => {
  const { counter } = useCounter();

  return <div>Prop: {counter.count}</div>;
};

const DisplayWithMemo = () => {
  const { counter } = useCounter();

  const val = useMemo(() => counter.count, [counter.count]);

  return <div>Memo: {val}</div>;
};

const Button = () => {
  const { counter } = useCounter();

  return <button onClick={counter.incrementCount}>Increment</button>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <CounterProvider>
      <DisplayWithMethod />
      <DisplayWithProperty />
      <DisplayWithMemo />
      <Button />
    </CounterProvider>
  );
}
```

None of these work since the counter instance never changes, so no re renders are triggered. Any idea(s) on how to make this work while keeping a class structure for `Counter`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-fast-cyflg

Comment: Hi, I assume you are giving a very simple reproduction.
What i suggest is, make your **Counter class** subscribe-able, subscribe with a forceUpdate function (get either from useState or useReducer). So when your Counter updating a value, it will trigger the subscriber and force react to re-render

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with React is not getting that the count has changed and does not rerender. You can get rid of the issue using `useState` hook.

You should change type definitions like below and construct counter instances using outputs of `useState` hook.

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

type CounterContextType = {
  counter: {
    count: number;
    getCount: () => number;
    incrementCount: () => void;
  };
};

const defaults: CounterContextType = {
  counter: {
    count: 0,
    getCount: () => 0,
    incrementCount: () => undefined
  }
};

const CounterContext = createContext<CounterContextType>(defaults);

export const CounterProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);

  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider
      value={{
        counter: {
          count,
          getCount: () => count,
          incrementCount: () => {
            setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
          }
        }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useCounter = () => {
  return useContext(CounterContext);
};
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-waterfall-90y35?file=/src/CounterProvider.tsx)

Comment: @klugjo, check this out !!

Comment: No reason to nest a`counter: {}` in the `value`

Comment: I agree that this is the right way to do it for this simple example. But I really need to reuse the `Counter` class directly and can't change it. Imagine thousands of lines of code inside `Counter`, if I were to change it to using your pattern, it's not feasible